# How to persist Inner Object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

What im trying to do is to try and persist the User Object which is using the Username and Password Properties in the HTML.

But the problem is, that when i click the submit button the User Object does not keep a hold of the updated Text Values from the TextBox's

I have a form with two text fields username and password

```
@Imports InstantForum.Controller

@ModelType InstantForum.Window

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code




@Using (Html.BeginForm("LoginUser", "Login", FormMethod.Post ))

    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) CType(Model.ModelObject, User).Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) CType(Model.ModelObject, User).Username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) CType(Model.ModelObject, User).Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) CType(Model.ModelObject, User).Password)

    @<input type="submit" value="Create" />

End Using
```

This is my controller

```
Namespace InstantForum
Public Class LoginController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /Login

    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim id As Integer = CInt(Me.Request.QueryString("id"))
        Dim width As Integer = CInt(Me.Request.QueryString("width"))
        Dim height As Integer = CInt(Me.Request.QueryString("height"))
        Dim color As Integer = CInt(Me.Request.QueryString("color"))

        Dim mUser = New Controller.User With {.Username = "redoc01", .Password = "ullafi01"}
        Dim mWindow As New Window With {.Color = color, .Id = id, .Width = width, .Height = height, .ModelObject = mUser}

        Return View("Index", mWindow)

    End Function

    <HttpPost> _
    Public Function LoginUser(windowControl As Window) As ViewResult

        If True Then

        End If


    End Function


End Class
```

End Namespace

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: In LoginUser Function put Me.Request with a breakpoint , and check to see what is in there

Comment: Scoot Selby: Hi, Great i found in the Form Object i can retrieve the values that you suggested. Just another question, When i do this is the page refreshing or is it like ajax?

Comment: I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In `LoginUser` Function put `Me.Request` with a break point , and check to see what is in there

This is not an AJAX request.  The page will not necessarily be refreshing, it will do what ever you tell it to do at the end of this action.  Don't just leave it as

```
 If True Then
        End If

    End Function
```

You have to return the User to the View of your choice.

See how the `Index` Action specifies which view to go to?

```
Return View("Index", mWindow)
```